# Akka Http - "Type mismatch" while parsing DateTime into json

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http, spray

I have created simple trait which should convert models into json:

```
trait Protocols extends SprayJsonSupport with DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val travelFormat = jsonFormat4(Travel)
}
```

I have a `Travel` model which looks like:

```
case class Travel(id: Option[Long] = None,
                  startDate: DateTime,
                  endDate: DateTime,
                  name: String,
                  description: String,
                  amount: BigDecimal)
```

But the problem is (as I found out) in `DateTime` class. In this code I get a compiler error on `jsonFormat4` method:

```
Type mismatch, expected: (NotInferedP1, NotInferedP2, NotInferedP3, NotInferedP4) => NotInferedT, actual: (Option[Long], DateTime, DateTime, String, String, BigDecimal) => Travel
```

When I remove all `DateTime` fields it works well. But in my case, I need this fields. So how shoud I fix it? I tried give a default parameter to them, but it also did not work.

Comment: Probably, it's related to this issue: https://github.com/spray/spray-json/issues/128.
And the only option is to define your own formatter

Comment: Yes. Probably it is a solution. Silly thing.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try writing a custom formatter like this for example:

```
 implicit val travelFormat: Format[Travel] =
    new Format[Travel] {
       for {
          id <- (json \ "id").validate[Int]
          startDate <- (json \ "startDate").validate[FiniteDuration]
          endDate <- (json \ "endDate").validate[FiniteDuration]
          ....
        } yield {
          Travel(
            id = id,
            startDate = startDate,
            endDate = endDate,
            ....
          )
        }
    }
```

I'm using the play-json library in the above example!

Comment: It is an option. But does Akka has any user friendly auto formatter? I really need to write own formatter to parse dates?

Comment: I tried to use your code, but I got an compiler error: `Too many arguments for method parameters(ToResponseMarshallable)`